First compile on React Native Expo Router for iOS failing
This is the complete log :
eas build --platform ios --local
Loaded "env" configuration for the "production" profile: no environment variables specified. Learn more
✔ Using remote iOS credentials (Expo server)

If you provide your Apple account credentials we will be able to generate all necessary build credentials and fully validate them.
This is optional, but without Apple account access you will need to provide all the missing values manually and we can only run minimal validation on them.
✔ Do you want to log in to your Apple account? … yes

› Log in to your Apple Developer account to continue
✔ Apple ID: … web@company.com
› Restoring session /Users/company/.app-store/auth/web@company.com/cookie
› Team Company LLC (AW3GS2F7X9)
› Provider Company LLC (124229229)
✔ Logged in Local session
✔ Bundle identifier registered com.company.appName
✔ Synced capabilities: No updates
✔ Synced capability identifiers: No updates
✔ Fetched Apple distribution certificates
✔ Fetched Apple provisioning profiles

Project Credentials Configuration

Project                   @user/appName
Bundle Identifier         com.company.appName
                          
App Store Configuration   
                          
Distribution Certificate  
Serial Number             2E174DFFAE686B7557D0465144AEAF8E
Expiration Date           Thu, 17 Apr 2025 15:13:39 EDT
Apple Team                AW3GS2F7X9 (Company LLC (Company/Organization))
Updated                   1 day ago
                          
Provisioning Profile      
Developer Portal ID       985BZ9KB35
Status                    active
Expiration                Thu, 17 Apr 2025 15:13:39 EDT
Apple Team                AW3GS2F7X9 (Company LLC (Company/Organization))
Updated                   4 hours ago
                          
All credentials are ready to build @user/appName (com.company.appName)

✔ Push Notifications setup for appName: com.company.appName
[SETUP_WORKINGDIR] Preparing workingdir /var/folders/n9/dnh0b5dj4v3g3h5g7tgwpps40000gp/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/442dc239-eb5c-4e33-9477-89436045fb8d
[START_BUILD] Starting build
  "job": {
    "type": "managed",
    "platform": "ios",
    "projectArchive": {
      "type": "PATH",
      "path": "/var/folders/n9/dnh0b5dj4v3g3h5g7tgwpps40000gp/T/eas-cli-nodejs/bcb409dd-aae3-4e93-84df-d58927031f39.tar.gz"
    },
    "projectRootDirectory": ".",
    "builderEnvironment": {},
    "cache": {
      "disabled": false,
      "paths": [],
      "clear": false
    },
    "updates": {},
    "scheme": "appName",
    "username": "user",
    "experimental": {},
    "mode": "build",
    "triggeredBy": "EAS_CLI"
  }
[READ_PACKAGE_JSON] Using package.json:
[READ_PACKAGE_JSON] {
  "name": "appName",
  "main": "expo-router/entry",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "test": "jest --watchAll"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.17",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.29",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.45",
    "expo": "~50.0.14",
    "expo-font": "~11.10.3",
    "expo-linking": "~6.2.2",
    "expo-router": "~3.4.8",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.26.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
    "expo-system-ui": "~2.9.3",
    "expo-web-browser": "~12.8.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.6",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.8.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.29.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.45",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^10.0.2",
    "jest": "^29.3.1",
    "jest-expo": "^50.0.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
[INSTALL_DEPENDENCIES] Running "yarn install" in /var/folders/n9/dnh0b5dj4v3g3h5g7tgwpps40000gp/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/442dc239-eb5c-4e33-9477-89436045fb8d/build directory
[INSTALL_DEPENDENCIES] yarn install v1.22.22
[INSTALL_DEPENDENCIES] [1/4] Resolving packages...
[INSTALL_DEPENDENCIES] [2/4] Fetching packages...
[INSTALL_DEPENDENCIES] [3/4] Linking dependencies...
[INSTALL_DEPENDENCIES] warning " > @react-navigation/stack@6.3.29" has unmet peer dependency "react-native-gesture-handler@>= 1.0.0".
[INSTALL_DEPENDENCIES] warning "expo > @expo/metro-config@0.17.7" has unmet peer dependency "@react-native/babel-preset@*".
[INSTALL_DEPENDENCIES] warning "react-native > @react-native/codegen@0.73.3" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/preset-env@^7.1.6".
[INSTALL_DEPENDENCIES] warning " > expo-router@3.4.8" has unmet peer dependency "expo-constants@*".
[INSTALL_DEPENDENCIES] warning "expo-router > expo-splash-screen > @expo/prebuild-config@6.7.4" has unmet peer dependency "expo-modules-autolinking@>=0.8.1".
[INSTALL_DEPENDENCIES] [4/4] Building fresh packages...
[INSTALL_DEPENDENCIES] Done in 4.05s.
[READ_APP_CONFIG] Using app configuration:
[READ_APP_CONFIG] {
  "name": "appName",
  "slug": "appName",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "icon": "./assets/images/icon.png",
  "scheme": "myapp",
  "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
  "splash": {
    "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
    "resizeMode": "contain",
    "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
  },
  "assetBundlePatterns": [
    "**/*"
  ],
  "ios": {
    "supportsTablet": true,
    "bundleIdentifier": "com.company.appName"
  },
  "android": {
    "adaptiveIcon": {
      "foregroundImage": "./assets/images/adaptive-icon.png",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "package": "com.company.appName"
  },
  "web": {
    "bundler": "metro",
    "output": "static",
    "favicon": "./assets/images/favicon.png"
  },
  "plugins": [
    "expo-router"
  ],
  "experiments": {
    "typedRoutes": true
  },
  "extra": {
    "router": {
      "origin": false
    },
    "eas": {
      "projectId": "52183979-9826-4840-93b2-b41860771214"
    }
  },
  "sdkVersion": "50.0.0",
  "platforms": [
    "ios",
    "android",
    "web"
  ]
}
[RUN_EXPO_DOCTOR] Running "expo doctor"
[RUN_EXPO_DOCTOR] Running 12 checks on your project...
[RUN_EXPO_DOCTOR] ✔ Check Expo config for common issues
[RUN_EXPO_DOCTOR] ✔ Check package.json for common issues
[RUN_EXPO_DOCTOR] ✔ Check native tooling versions
[RUN_EXPO_DOCTOR] ✔ Check dependencies for packages that should not be installed directly
[RUN_EXPO_DOCTOR] ✔ Check for common project setup issues
[RUN_EXPO_DOCTOR] ✔ Check for issues with metro config
[RUN_EXPO_DOCTOR] ✔ Check npm/ yarn versions
[RUN_EXPO_DOCTOR] ✔ Check Expo config (app.json/ app.config.js) schema
[RUN_EXPO_DOCTOR] ✖ Check that packages match versions required by installed Expo SDK
[RUN_EXPO_DOCTOR] ✔ Check for legacy global CLI installed locally
[RUN_EXPO_DOCTOR] ✔ Check that native modules do not use incompatible support packages
[RUN_EXPO_DOCTOR] ✔ Check that native modules use compatible support package versions for installed Expo SDK
[RUN_EXPO_DOCTOR] Detailed check results:
[RUN_EXPO_DOCTOR] CommandError: "jest" is added as a dependency in your project's package.json but it doesn't seem to be installed. Please run "yarn" or "npm install" to fix this issue.
[RUN_EXPO_DOCTOR] One or more checks failed, indicating possible issues with the project.
[RUN_EXPO_DOCTOR] Advice: Use 'npx expo install --check' to review and upgrade your dependencies.
[RUN_EXPO_DOCTOR] Command "expo doctor" failed.
Error: npx -y expo-doctor exited with non-zero code: 1
    at ChildProcess.completionListener (/Users/company/.npm/_npx/89fde002d95f40cb/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/build/spawnAsync.js:42:23)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:633:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1105:16)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:305:5)
    ...
    at spawnAsync (/Users/company/.npm/_npx/89fde002d95f40cb/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/build/spawnAsync.js:7:23)
    at spawn (/Users/company/.npm/_npx/89fde002d95f40cb/node_modules/@expo/turtle-spawn/dist/index.js:16:47)
    at runExpoDoctor (/Users/company/.npm/_npx/89fde002d95f40cb/node_modules/@expo/build-tools/dist/common/setup.js:107:50)
    at async /Users/company/.npm/_npx/89fde002d95f40cb/node_modules/@expo/build-tools/dist/common/setup.js:80:36
    at async BuildContext.runBuildPhase (/Users/company/.npm/_npx/89fde002d95f40cb/node_modules/@expo/build-tools/dist/context.js:98:28)
    at async setupAsync (/Users/company/.npm/_npx/89fde002d95f40cb/node_modules/@expo/build-tools/dist/common/setup.js:78:9)
    at async buildAsync (/Users/company/.npm/_npx/89fde002d95f40cb/node_modules/@expo/build-tools/dist/builders/ios.js:42:5)
    at async runBuilderWithHooksAsync (/Users/company/.npm/_npx/89fde002d95f40cb/node_modules/@expo/build-tools/dist/builders/common.js:12:13)
    at async Object.iosBuilder (/Users/company/.npm/_npx/89fde002d95f40cb/node_modules/@expo/build-tools/dist/builders/ios.js:28:16)
    at async buildIosAsync (/Users/company/.npm/_npx/89fde002d95f40cb/node_modules/eas-cli-local-build-plugin/dist/ios.js:43:12)
[PREPARE_CREDENTIALS] Preparing credentials
[PREPARE_CREDENTIALS] Creating keychain
[PREPARE_CREDENTIALS] Preparing credentials for target 'appName'
[PREPARE_CREDENTIALS] Getting distribution certificate fingerprint and common name
[PREPARE_CREDENTIALS] Fingerprint = "3DA63FFD08E4AD7ACE457C3DD0DB7445C7D2EFFF", common name = iPhone Distribution: Company LLC (AW3GS2F7X9)
[PREPARE_CREDENTIALS] Writing distribution certificate to /var/folders/n9/dnh0b5dj4v3g3h5g7tgwpps40000gp/T/882e0747-becd-44da-b3df-ca547e9d8350.p12
[PREPARE_CREDENTIALS] Importing distribution certificate into the keychain
[PREPARE_CREDENTIALS] Initializing provisioning profile
[PREPARE_CREDENTIALS] Validating whether the distribution certificate has been imported successfully
[PREPARE_CREDENTIALS] Verifying whether the distribution certificate and provisioning profile match
[PREBUILD] yarn run v1.22.22
[PREBUILD] $ /private/var/folders/n9/dnh0b5dj4v3g3h5g7tgwpps40000gp/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/442dc239-eb5c-4e33-9477-89436045fb8d/build/node_modules/.bin/expo prebuild --no-install --platform ios
[PREBUILD] - Creating native directory (./ios)
[PREBUILD] ✔ Created native directory
[PREBUILD] - Updating package.json
[PREBUILD] ✔ Updated package.json
[PREBUILD] - Running prebuild
[PREBUILD] ✔ Finished prebuild
[PREBUILD] Done in 1.87s.
[PREBUILD] Running "yarn install" in /var/folders/n9/dnh0b5dj4v3g3h5g7tgwpps40000gp/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/442dc239-eb5c-4e33-9477-89436045fb8d/build directory
[PREBUILD] yarn install v1.22.22
[PREBUILD] [1/4] Resolving packages...
[PREBUILD] success Already up-to-date.
[PREBUILD] Done in 0.16s.
[INSTALL_PODS] Using Expo modules
[INSTALL_PODS] [Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod ExpoModulesCore
[INSTALL_PODS] Auto-linking React Native modules for target `appName`: RNScreens and react-native-safe-area-context
[INSTALL_PODS] Framework build type is static library
[INSTALL_PODS] [Codegen] Generating ./build/generated/ios/React-Codegen.podspec.json
[INSTALL_PODS] [Codegen] generating an empty RCTThirdPartyFabricComponentsProvider
[INSTALL_PODS] Analyzing dependencies
[INSTALL_PODS] Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
[INSTALL_PODS] [Codegen] Found FBReactNativeSpec
[INSTALL_PODS] Fetching podspec for `RCT-Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/RCT-Folly.podspec`
[INSTALL_PODS] [Codegen] Found rncore
[INSTALL_PODS] Fetching podspec for `boost` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/boost.podspec`
[INSTALL_PODS] Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
[INSTALL_PODS] Fetching podspec for `hermes-engine` from `../node_modules/react-native/sdks/hermes-engine/hermes-engine.podspec`
[INSTALL_PODS] [Hermes] Using release tarball from URL: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/facebook/react/react-native-artifacts/0.73.6/react-native-artifacts-0.73.6-hermes-ios-debug.tar.gz
[INSTALL_PODS] % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average
[INSTALL_PODS] Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
[INSTALL_PODS]                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
[INSTALL_PODS] 100 16.2M  100 16.2M    0     0  46.4M
[INSTALL_PODS] 0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 46.4M
[INSTALL_PODS] % Total    % Received % Xferd  Ave
[INSTALL_PODS] rage Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
[INSTALL_PODS]                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
[INSTALL_PODS] 84 12.3M   84 10.3M    0     0  35.6M      0 --:--:-- --:--:--
[INSTALL_PODS] --:--:-- 35.5M
[INSTALL_PODS] 100 12.3M  100 12.3M    0     0  3
[INSTALL_PODS] 7.9M      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 37.9M
[INSTALL_PODS] Downloading dependencies
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing DoubleConversion (1.1.6)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing EXConstants (15.4.6)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing EXFont (11.10.3)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing EXSplashScreen (0.26.4)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing Expo (50.0.17)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing ExpoFileSystem (16.0.9)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing ExpoHead (3.4.8)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing ExpoKeepAwake (12.8.2)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing ExpoModulesCore (1.11.13)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing ExpoSystemUI (2.9.4)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing ExpoWebBrowser (12.8.2)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing FBLazyVector (0.73.6)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing FBReactNativeSpec (0.73.6)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing RCT-Folly (2022.05.16.00)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing RCTRequired (0.73.6)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing RCTTypeSafety (0.73.6)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing RNScreens (3.29.0)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing React (0.73.6)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing React-Codegen (0.73.6)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing React-Core (0.73.6)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing React-CoreModules (0.73.6)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing React-Fabric (0.73.6)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing React-FabricImage (0.73.6)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing React-ImageManager (0.73.6)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing React-Mapbuffer (0.73.6)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing React-NativeModulesApple (0.73.6)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing React-RCTActionSheet (0.73.6)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing React-RCTAnimation (0.73.6)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing React-RCTAppDelegate (0.73.6)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing React-RCTBlob (0.73.6)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing React-RCTFabric (0.73.6)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing React-RCTImage (0.73.6)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing React-RCTLinking (0.73.6)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing React-RCTNetwork (0.73.6)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing React-RCTSettings (0.73.6)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing React-RCTText (0.73.6)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing React-RCTVibration (0.73.6)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing React-callinvoker (0.73.6)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing React-cxxreact (0.73.6)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing React-debug (0.73.6)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing React-graphics (0.73.6)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing React-hermes (0.73.6)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing React-jserrorhandler (0.73.6)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing React-jsi (0.73.6)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing React-jsiexecutor (0.73.6)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing React-jsinspector (0.73.6)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing React-logger (0.73.6)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing React-nativeconfig (0.73.6)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing React-perflogger (0.73.6)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing React-rendererdebug (0.73.6)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing React-rncore (0.73.6)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing React-runtimeexecutor (0.73.6)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing React-runtimescheduler (0.73.6)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing React-utils (0.73.6)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing ReactCommon (0.73.6)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing SocketRocket (0.6.1)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing Yoga (1.14.0)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing boost (1.83.0)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing fmt (6.2.1)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing glog (0.3.5)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing hermes-engine (0.73.6)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing libevent (2.1.12)
[INSTALL_PODS] Installing react-native-safe-area-context (4.8.2)
[INSTALL_PODS] Generating Pods project
[INSTALL_PODS] Setting USE_HERMES build settings
[INSTALL_PODS] Setting REACT_NATIVE build settings
[INSTALL_PODS] Setting CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD to c++20 on /private/var/folders/n9/dnh0b5dj4v3g3h5g7tgwpps40000gp/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/442dc239-eb5c-4e33-9477-89436045fb8d/build/ios/appName.xcodeproj
[INSTALL_PODS] Pod install took 11 [s] to run
[INSTALL_PODS] Integrating client project
[INSTALL_PODS] [!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `appName.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.
[INSTALL_PODS] [Expo] Installing the build script for target appName
[INSTALL_PODS] expo_patch_react_imports! took 0.0818 seconds to transform files.
[INSTALL_PODS] Pod installation complete! There are 63 dependencies from the Podfile and 63 total pods installed.
[INSTALL_PODS] [!] `<PBXResourcesBuildPhase UUID=`13B07F8E1A680F5B00A75B9A`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `4217A550C682447C85F17E24` for attribute: `files`. This can be the result of a merge and the unknown UUID is being discarded.
[INSTALL_PODS] [!] hermes-engine has added 1 script phase. Please inspect before executing a build. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#script_phases` for more information.
[CONFIGURE_XCODE_PROJECT] Configuring Xcode project
[CONFIGURE_XCODE_PROJECT] Assigning provisioning profile '*[expo] com.company.appName AppStore 2024-04-18T18:40:00.583Z' (Apple Team ID: AW3GS2F7X9) to target 'appName'
[RUN_FASTLANE] Creating Gymfile
[RUN_FASTLANE] Gymfile created
[RUN_FASTLANE] Successfully loaded '/private/var/folders/n9/dnh0b5dj4v3g3h5g7tgwpps40000gp/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/442dc239-eb5c-4e33-9477-89436045fb8d/build/ios/Gymfile' 
[RUN_FASTLANE] +--------------------------------------------------------------+
[RUN_FASTLANE] |               Detected Values from './Gymfile'               |
[RUN_FASTLANE] +-----------------------+--------------------------------------+
[RUN_FASTLANE] | suppress_xcode_output | true                                 |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | clean                 | false                                |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | scheme                | appName                            |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | configuration         | Release                              |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | export_options        | {:method=>"app-store",               |
[RUN_FASTLANE] |                       | :provisioningProfiles=>{"com.company.my  |
[RUN_FASTLANE] |                       | App”=>"76dec0ee-7710-4d4b-ae23-  |
[RUN_FASTLANE] |                       | 86170124d902"}}                      |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | export_xcargs         | OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS="--keychain    |
[RUN_FASTLANE] |                       | /var/folders/n9/dnh0b5dj4v3g3h5g7tg  |
[RUN_FASTLANE] |                       | wpps40000gp/T/eas-build-ef6e19a5-f8  |
[RUN_FASTLANE] |                       | 5c-4c98-a809-7b0cfa4a3ba7.keychain"  |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | disable_xcpretty      | true                                 |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | buildlog_path         | /var/folders/n9/dnh0b5dj4v3g3h5g7tg  |
[RUN_FASTLANE] |                       | wpps40000gp/T/eas-build-local-nodej  |
[RUN_FASTLANE] |                       | s/442dc239-eb5c-4e33-9477-89436045f  |
[RUN_FASTLANE] |                       | b8d/logs                             |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | output_directory      | ./build                              |
[RUN_FASTLANE] +-----------------------+--------------------------------------+
[RUN_FASTLANE] Resolving Swift Package Manager dependencies...
[RUN_FASTLANE] $ xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies -workspace ./appName.xcworkspace -scheme appName -configuration Release
[RUN_FASTLANE] ▸ Command line invocation:
[RUN_FASTLANE] ▸     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies -workspace ./appName.xcworkspace -scheme appName -configuration Release
[RUN_FASTLANE] ▸ User defaults from command line:
[RUN_FASTLANE] ▸     IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES
[RUN_FASTLANE] ▸ resolved source packages:
[RUN_FASTLANE] $ xcodebuild -showBuildSettings -workspace ./appName.xcworkspace -scheme appName -configuration Release 2>&1
[RUN_FASTLANE] Detected provisioning profile mapping: {:"com.company.appName"=>"76dec0ee-7710-4d4b-ae23-86170124d902"}
[RUN_FASTLANE] 
[RUN_FASTLANE] +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[RUN_FASTLANE] |                           Summary for gym 2.220.0                           |
[RUN_FASTLANE] +--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
[RUN_FASTLANE] | workspace                            | ./appName.xcworkspace              |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | scheme                               | appName                            |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | clean                                | false                                |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | output_directory                     | ./build                              |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | output_name                          | appName                            |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | configuration                        | Release                              |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | silent                               | false                                |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | skip_package_ipa                     | false                                |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | skip_package_pkg                     | false                                |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | export_options.method                | app-store                            |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | export_options.provisioningProfiles  | 76dec0ee-7710-4d4b-ae23-86170124d90  |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | .com.company.appName                   | 2                                    |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | export_xcargs                        | OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS="--keychain    |
[RUN_FASTLANE] |                                      | /var/folders/n9/dnh0b5dj4v3g3h5g7tg  |
[RUN_FASTLANE] |                                      | wpps40000gp/T/eas-build-ef6e19a5-f8  |
[RUN_FASTLANE] |                                      | 5c-4c98-a809-7b0cfa4a3ba7.keychain"  |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | build_path                           | /Users/company/Library/Developer/Xcode/  |
[RUN_FASTLANE] |                                      | Archives/2024-04-18                  |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | result_bundle                        | false                                |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | buildlog_path                        | /var/folders/n9/dnh0b5dj4v3g3h5g7tg  |
[RUN_FASTLANE] |                                      | wpps40000gp/T/eas-build-local-nodej  |
[RUN_FASTLANE] |                                      | s/442dc239-eb5c-4e33-9477-89436045f  |
[RUN_FASTLANE] |                                      | b8d/logs                             |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | destination                          | generic/platform=iOS                 |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | suppress_xcode_output                | true                                 |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | xcodebuild_formatter                 | xcpretty                             |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | build_timing_summary                 | false                                |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | disable_xcpretty                     | true                                 |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | skip_profile_detection               | false                                |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | xcodebuild_command                   | xcodebuild                           |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | skip_package_dependencies_resolutio  | false                                |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | n                                    |                                      |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | disable_package_automatic_updates    | false                                |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | use_system_scm                       | false                                |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | xcode_path                           | /Applications/Xcode.app              |
[RUN_FASTLANE] +--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
[RUN_FASTLANE] $ set -o pipefail && xcodebuild -workspace ./appName.xcworkspace -scheme appName -configuration Release -destination 'generic/platform=iOS' -archivePath /Users/company/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2024-04-18/appName\ 2024-04-18\ 18.56.26.xcarchive archive | tee /var/folders/n9/dnh0b5dj4v3g3h5g7tgwpps40000gp/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/442dc239-eb5c-4e33-9477-89436045fb8d/logs/appName-appName.log > /dev/null
[RUN_FASTLANE] ▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
[RUN_FASTLANE] ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
[RUN_FASTLANE] Exit status: 65
[RUN_FASTLANE] 
[RUN_FASTLANE] +---------------------------------------+
[RUN_FASTLANE] |           Build environment           |
[RUN_FASTLANE] +-------------+-------------------------+
[RUN_FASTLANE] | xcode_path  | /Applications/Xcode.app |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | gym_version | 2.220.0                 |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | sdk         | iPhoneOS17.4.sdk        |
[RUN_FASTLANE] +-------------+-------------------------+
[RUN_FASTLANE] Looks like fastlane ran into a build/archive error with your project
[RUN_FASTLANE] It's hard to tell what's causing the error, so we wrote some guides on how
[RUN_FASTLANE] to troubleshoot build and signing issues: https://docs.fastlane.tools/codesigning/getting-started/
[RUN_FASTLANE] Before submitting an issue on GitHub, please follow the guide above and make
[RUN_FASTLANE] sure your project is set up correctly.
[RUN_FASTLANE] fastlane uses `xcodebuild` commands to generate your binary, you can see the
[RUN_FASTLANE] the full commands are printed out in yellow in the above log.
[RUN_FASTLANE] Make sure to inspect the output above, as usually you'll find more error information there
[RUN_FASTLANE] 
[RUN_FASTLANE] [!] Error building the application - see the log above
[RUN_FASTLANE] Error: The "Run fastlane" step failed with an unknown error. Refer to "Xcode Logs" below for additional, more detailed logs.
[CLEAN_UP_CREDENTIALS] Destroying keychain - /var/folders/n9/dnh0b5dj4v3g3h5g7tgwpps40000gp/T/eas-build-ef6e19a5-f85c-4c98-a809-7b0cfa4a3ba7.keychain
[CLEAN_UP_CREDENTIALS] Removing provisioning profile

Build failed
The "Run fastlane" step failed with an unknown error. Refer to "Xcode Logs" below for additional, more detailed logs.
npx exited with non-zero code: 1
    Error: build command failed.


I just initialized a project in React Native Expo Router using the quickstart option as described in the React Expo documentation using:
npx create-expo-app@latest --template tabs@50
and then:
npx expo start
I have tried restarting from scratch deleting all Apple certificates and re-installing them. It compiles just fine for Android. The app is just the template you get from the quickstart, with no extra code written or dependencies installed.
If I run npx expo-doctor, I get this:

✔ Check Expo config for common issues
✔ Check package.json for common issues
✔ Check native tooling versions
✔ Check dependencies for packages that should not be installed directly
✔ Check for common project setup issues
✔ Check for issues with the metro config
✔ Check npm/ yarn versions
✔ Check Expo config (app.json/ app.config.js) schema
✔ Check that packages match the versions required by the installed Expo SDK
✔ Check that native modules do not use incompatible support packages
✔ Check for legacy global CLI installed locally
✔ Check that native modules use compatible support package versions for installed Expo SDK

Didn't find any issues with the project!

I expected expo-doctor to behave the same but it actually fails when building for iOS.
I also tried installing jest and jest-expo and they install with yarn with their respective folders in node_modules.
After the expo server starts and I verify it runs, I exit. I tried packaging it for iOS with:
eas build --platform ios --local
Then I get the log above. I expected the app to compile just as in Android. I did setup my Apple developer account, certificates and keys.
I am running the latest versions of Cocoapods, Xcode, Fastlane and Ruby on an M1 MacBook Pro with macOS Sonoma.
Thanks in advance.

Try Removing node modules and installing them once again...


rm -rf node_modules
npm install




You can run this command- npx expo install --fix  and then try to make build
and If you are still getting error after this, then you can share your eas.json file.

I run into similar symptoms i.e. local eas ios build complaining about JEST in  Fastlane RUN_EXPO_DOCTOR phase, and build failing later with a strange unresolved import error. My project had been compiling without problems until this issue suddenly appeared.
In my case the problem was NODE_ENV=production which I set in my package.json build script. NODE_ENV=development or no NODE_ENV works without problems. I had set the NODE_ENV because build script complains about it if not defined...
